# Best practices to replace a set of characters stored in MySQL after being selected and echo'd with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, str-replace

The goal I am trying to accomplish is a work-around method to store a PHP variable in MySQL. One of the columns in this table is storing words such as {{literature}}, or {{coffee}}, etc.

[image: sys_format]

My second table has the name of the person who has that job in a group.

[image: sys_commits]

What is the best way to use str_replace to change {{chips}} to the variable that is stored in the second screenshot after it has been echo'd out in PHP?

This is my php code that selects the content from sys_format (first image):

```
// Select THIRD associated meeting format item based on selected meeting 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM sys_format WHERE sys_meeting_related = '$sys_current_meeting' AND sys_format_order_id = '3'";
            $result = $con->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "  
                        <h4>" .$row['sys_format_name']. "</h4>
                            <blockquote class='topmargin bottommargin'>
                                <p>" .$row['sys_format_content']. "</p>
                            </blockquote>";
                }
            }
```

The problem i am facing with PHP's `str_replace()` function is that the parameters it has to follow won't work for the method I am calling the content. The content is question to be replaced is coming from the above select statement and is dynamic so I cannot specifcy the string to be searched.

Javascript's `replace()` functions seems to have similar limitations, unless I'm misunderstanding you need to define the string to be searched. Same issue there.

Did I miss something? Thank you all in advance for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: Join the tables in the query on `sys_meeting_related` then in the loop before `echo`  use `str_ireplace` using the data from the other table.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks.. what would the subject be in `str_replace` using your example?

Comment: Something like `$row['sys_format_content'] = str_ireplace('{{'.$row['sys_commit_name'].'}}', $row['sys_commit_assignee'], $row['sys_format_content']);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above comment from @AbraCadaver, I was able to make this work. (Yes I realize these statements are vulnerable to sql injection.. This is only for practice purposes.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sys_commits WHERE sys_commit_name = 'Secretary' AND sys_meeting_related = '$sys_current_meeting'";
                $result = $con->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $secretary_commit_assignee = $row['sys_commit_assignee'];
                    }
                }

                // Select FIRST associated meeting format item based on selected meeting
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM sys_format WHERE sys_meeting_related = '$sys_current_meeting' AND sys_format_order_id = '1'";
                $result = $con->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $sys_format_name = $row['sys_format_name'];
                        $sys_format_content = $row['sys_format_content'];

                    }
                }

                echo str_ireplace("{{secretary}}", "$secretary_commit_assignee", "$sys_format_content");"
                            <h4>$sys_format_name</h4>
                                <blockquote class='topmargin bottommargin'>
                                    <p>$sys_format_content</p>
                                </blockquote>";
```

Hopefully this helps someone down the road.
Cheers to all.